# Windows driver signed using Vista and later methods installs just fine in XP, but it shouldn't?

Tags: usb, windows-xp, driver, hid, driver-signing

My company makes a measurement device that connects to the PC via USB and used to use the Windows in-box USB HID driver. I'm using a different driver now to control the device and I am in the process of signing these drivers for many Windows versions. The reason being we want our customers to be able to install our measurement software (which would pre-install these new drivers), plug in our measurement device, and have Windows trust and use our new driver in favor of the in-box USB HID driver. It would also have the added benefit of using this new driver each time the device is connected no matter what USB port is used or if the user connects a unit that has a different serial number in the descriptor.

I've read through and performed the steps outlined in the KMCS_Walkthrough written by Microsoft to perform Test Signing of this driver by creating a catalog file for Windows 7 x64 from the inf file and signing the catalog file with a self-signed certificate. Things seemed to work smoothly on a Windows 7 x64 machine when rebooted into Test Mode. What surprised me was that I was able to create an XP_x86 catalog file, sign it with my test certificate, import my test certificate into the Trusted Root store and get the driver behavior I wanted on a  Windows XP machine. The default driver signing policy was set to the default (Warn - Prompt me each time to choose an action).

I'm surprised because all of the MSDN documentation I have been reading about signing drivers for public release for XP seems to have a strict stance on the drivers being WHQL certified in order for the drivers to be fully trusted as opposed to obtaining a code-signing certificate from a third party and using that to sign the driver. Is this not true? How could my self-signed drivers out-rank the in-box USB HID driver in Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A LOT more trial, error, and research, I've finally come to a conclusion.

The key in my initial question was that I was using a self-signed certificate. I generated the self-signed certificate in Windows using makcert and following the example in the KMCS_Walkthrough:

```
makecert -r -pe -ss PrivateStore -n CN=CompanyName MyCertificate.cer
```

The parameter which specifies what Enhanced Key Usages (EKUs) the certificate should be valid for (-eku) is not included. What I didn't know was that with this parameter missing, this creates a self-signed certificate with ALL EKUs. Most notably the EKU called "Windows System Component Verification (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.6)". This EKU is included in certificates for WHQL signing.

So, in fact, Windows XP was behaving appropriately. My driver was indeed WHQL signed, it was just a self-signed WHQL certificate that was used.

Answer (score 1):

I think your experience is normal.

At my company, we have distributed USB drivers to Windows XP users and we never had to sign them to get them installed.  We later starting signing them ourselves, but that did not really affect the Windows XP user experience.

Our drivers were usually INF-only or they used WinUSB, so that might be different from you if you are compiling binary drivers.

Without a WHQL signature, Windows XP users can still install your driver package as long at they click through this warning:

[image]

After the driver package is installed, in my experience there is nothing that prevents the kernel modules it contains from being loaded into the kernel.  However, our users always had to go through the "Found New Hardware Wizard" whenever plugging a new device into their computer for the first time.

Perhaps your driver outranks the HID driver because you picked a more specific identifier string (i.e. one with a vendor ID and product ID in it).

For more information I recommend reading my article: [Practical Windows Code and Driver Signing](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/).

Comment: Hi David. Funny you responded because I had just read your article (along with 1,000 pages of MSDN articles and Google searches) right before posting here.

My drivers are INF only as well. How did you go about installing your INF-only drivers?

I ask because my previous attempts at out-ranking the in-box USB HID driver did not work. So I could get one driver instance to install, but it would not stick if I switched USB ports or swapped units which had different serial numbers in the descriptor.

I had used DPInst and Devcon with the same results.

Comment: Our INF files have a DefaultInstall section that allows the user to install them by right-clicking and selecting "Install".  But these days we have nice installers that copy the driver package (INF and related files) to the hard drive and call SetupCopyOEMInf from a Win32 DLL that we wrote.  I never needed to out-rank a driver because our devices did not attempt to be some standard class.

Comment: It's important to note that after the user goes through the Found New Hardware Wizard, Windows remembers the results and will not use any new drivers when the device is plugged in.  So maybe you need to just tell Windows to Update Driver Software for the device?  Or try it on a fresh installation of Windows XP that hasn't learned to use the wrong driver?

Comment: Our USB device was designed to conform to the HID class. So when I connect it to a Windows XP machine, the in-box USB HID driver (stemming from input.inf) would always win unless I manually installed via the INF I created (either by using Device Manager, Devcon, or DPInst) while the device was connected (and by that time was already bound to the in-box USB HID driver). So the goal was to make our new driver win so that Windows XP would prefer it over the HID driver no matter when/how/why it was connected. I guess I'm a little surprised that XP fully trusted my self-signed driver package.